# Creating IIS Express Virtual Directories with VS2012 / Web Site (not WAP)

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-express, virtual-directory

I'm inheriting a web site project that was built with a virtual directory for user controls (still wondering why someone did that).  Of course, the src tags bombs when I load it into visual studio 2012 because those files are not actually there.

So, with vs2012 and iis express (build in browser) how can I easily create a virtual directory and have it resolve in my visual studio development experience.

Thanks! -Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out there is under the website menu an option that says "Create Virtual Directory". I'm hoping that is exactly what I want.